# Using randoms and super

Tags: java, random, compilation, super

How would I call a `Random` from `java.util.Random` into a `supertype constructor`?

For example

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomValue = rand.nextInt(10) + 5;

public Something() 
{
    super(randomValue);
    //Other Things
}
```

When I try this the compiler says that I "cannot reference `randomValue` before `supertype constructor` has been called".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `super()` call must be the first call in the constructor, and any expressions that initialize instance variables will only be evaluated after the super call returns. Therefore `super(randomValue)` attempts to pass the value of a variable not yet declared to the super class's constructor.

A possible solution is to make `rand` static (it makes sense to have a single random number generator for all instances of your class) and generate the random number in the constructor :

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public Something() 
{
    super(rand.nextInt(10) + 5);
    //Over Things
}
```

Comment: @SiyuanRen Pardon for me asking but what does thread safe mean?

Comment: @Dan: It means that constructing `Something` from different threads concurrently will lead to subtle bugs. beresfordt's answer does not have this problem.

Comment: According to its javadoc `Random` is thread safe, but with the caveat `concurrent use of the same Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.`

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution is to add a constructor parameter and have a factory method;

```
public class Something extends SomethingElse {
    private Something(int arg) {
        super(arg);
    }

    public static Something getSomething() {
        return new Something(new Random().nextInt(10) + 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not the most elegant solution, but another solution would be to have 2 constructors and no field.

```
public class Something extends SomethingElse{
    public Something(){
        this(new Random());
    }

    private Something(Random rand){
        super(rand.nextInt(10) + 5);
        //Other Things
    }
}
```